# grid search on own estimator with a continuous target in python

Tags: python, regression, knn, imputation

I wrote a KNN imputation implementation and I wanted the StratifiedKFold to check what K and what distance matrix to use. 
I got an error: it seems it doesn't recognize my estimator as a regressor (the "scoring" function is for regression).

My Code:

```
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=False, random_state=12)
NN = KnnImputation() # my own function
gridSearchNN = GridSearchCV(NN, param_grid=params, scoring='mean_squared_error', n_jobs=numIter,
                            cv=skf.split(xTrain, yTrain), verbose=verbose)
gridSearchNN.fit(xTrain, yTrain)
```

The Error:

```
  File "........\dataImputation.py", line 63, in knnImputationMethod
    gridSearchNN.fit(xTrain, yTrain)
  File "C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py", line 651, in fit
    cv = check_cv(self.cv, y, classifier=is_classifier(estimator))
  File "C:\Users\....\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py", line 2068, in check_cv
    return _CVIterableWrapper(cv)
  File "C:\Users\....\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py", line 1966, in __init__
    self.cv = list(cv)
  File "C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py", line 331, in split
    for train, test in super(_BaseKFold, self).split(X, y, groups):
  File "C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py", line 100, in split
    for test_index in self._iter_test_masks(X, y, groups):
  File "C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py", line 681, in _iter_test_masks
    test_folds = self._make_test_folds(X, y)
  File "C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py", line 636, in _make_test_folds
    allowed_target_types, type_of_target_y))
ValueError: Supported target types are: ('binary', 'multiclass'). Got 'continuous' instead.
```

In the "GridSearchCV" process I saw it went in to "is_classifier" instead of "is_regressor".

Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide the full error traceback, that will help. However, one glaring issue I see is this: _"it doesn't recognize my classifier as a regressor"_ ...nor should it! A classifier is very much NOT a regressor. If you built your base model on a classifier rather than a regressor, that's the problem I'd wager. [See this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141381/regression-vs-classification)

Comment: There's not enough detail in this question for a [mcve], it looks like something in the `\dataImputation.py", line 63, in knnImputationMethod
    gridSearchNN.fit(xTrain, yTrain)` but we don;t have that to look at

Comment: What is the base class(es) of your KnnImputation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> StratifiedKFold
>
> Takes group information into account to avoid building
> folds with imbalanced class distributions (for binary or multiclass
> classification tasks).

StratifiedKFold works only on classification data not for regression.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html

Replace `StratifiedKFold` with `KFold`

You can check the source here :

https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py#L570

Comment: still get the same error,  the "GridSearchCV" process I saw it went in to "is_classifier" instead of "is_regressor".

Comment: @anat you seem to have missed inheriting from `RegressorMixin`

Comment: @anat please check my edit. For custom estimators sklearn identified if it is a classifier or regressor using an attribute  "_estimator_type" which is set to "regressor" for regression. The correct way of doing is by inheriting your estimator from RegressorMixin class.

Comment: I corrected the code and I still get the same error.

Comment: sorry @anat I missed the fundamental problem :( StratifiedKFold cannot be used for regression. Changed my answer

Comment: tnx! I haven't even noticed I was using the Stratified version, I am so use to working with imbalanced data.